# javafx println() function won't work

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

This is part of a javafx application and for some reason the println function won't print "s". The print function works when I use a constructor of a certain object but it doesn't work when I put it straight into the start function.

```
   import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;



    public class DiabetesDatabaseInterface extends Application  {
    @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            System.out.println("s");
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch(args);
        }

    }
```

Comment: For me the code sample you provided does print out 's'. Using IntelliJ.

Comment: probably crashes before that line?

Answer (score 0):

The start method should throw an exception.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
System.out.println("s");
}
```

This may fix your problem.